# How to use string as data for plotting in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, plot

I want to use a words like, let's say, 'A', 'B' and 'C' on X-axis to show their corresponding properties on Y-axis. How can I write these strings on X-axis instead of numerical data?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `'XTick'` and `'XTickLabel'` properties of the axes handle.
Here's a simple example:

```
x = 1:5;
y = rand(size(x));
plot(x, y, 'b')
set(gca, 'XTick',1:5, 'XTickLabel',{'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E'})
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Have you got any pointers to get the cell items to be interpreted by the LaTeX interpreter? So that this renders the symbol correctly: `set(gca, 'XTick',1:5, 'XTickLabel',{'A' 'B' '- \sigma' '\sigma' 'E'})` ?

Comment: @David_G: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/09/24/tex-interpreter-in-x-tick-and-y-tick-labels/ (you can find other similar submissions on the File Exchange). The idea is to replace the tick labels with actual `text` objects located at the correct positions

Answer (score 10):

Set yourself up a cell with your letters (mine's called labels), then use the XTick property to set the same amount of ticks on the x axis as your label number. Finally, the XTickLabel property will write your labels to the x axis.

```
x = yourXdata;
y = yourYdata;
labels = {'A' 'B' 'C'};
plot(x, y);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:3, 'XTickLabel', labels);
```

Answer (score 1):

How to use CHARACTER Values instead of Numerical values in X axis.
to label x as T1 T2 T3 T4 just use this :
set(gca,'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4'},'FontSize',15)

this command can be used after the plot command followed by the xlabel and ylabel , legand commands.
you can also adjust the font size.

Practical Example:

```
    %% 50% Day 
    T1wSI=[54.17 115];
    T2wSI=[53.5 112];
    T3wSI=[52.2 110];
    T4wSI=[51.2 108];

    T1oSI=[50.25 94];
    T2oSI=[49.18 92];
    T3oSI=[48.2 90];
    T4oSI=[46.1 84];

    table1=[T1wSI;T2wSI;T3wSI;T4wSI;T1oSI;T2oSI;T3oSI;T4oSI ];
    season2012=table1(:,1);
    season2013=table1(:,2);
    Tr1=[1 2 3 4];

Treatment1 =['T1wSI' 'T2wSI' 'T3wSI' 'T4wSI' 'T1oSI' 'T2oSI' 'T3oSI' 'T4oSI'];
    %Tre1=['T1' 'T2' 'T3' 'T4'];
    %set(gca,'FontSize',14)
    figure(1)
    set(gca,'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4'},'FontSize',14)
    plot(Tr1,table1(1:4,1),'--bs','LineWidth',3);% 2012
    hold on;
    plot(Tr1,table1(1:4,2),'-go','LineWidth',3);% 2013
    plot(Tr1,table1(5:8,1),'--r*','LineWidth',3); % 2012
    plot(Tr1,table1(5:8,2),'-m^','LineWidth',3);% 2013
    set(gca,'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4'},'FontSize',15)
    xlim=[1 5];
    xlabel('Treatments')
    ylabel('Days to 50 % Flowering')
    legend('With -Season 2012','Without -Season 2013','With -Season 2012','Without - Season 2013','Location','NorthEast');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the GUI.

1) Click on the figure axes to to open the Axes Property Editor.

2) Click on the "More properties" button on the right side of the window. This will open the inspector window of the axes.

3) Click on the small button next to "XTickLabel" property to open the dialogue box as shown below.
[image]

4) Enter the labels you want and click on "OK".