# Matlab horizontal axis labeling with TEX interpreter

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672637/how-to-use-string-as-data-for-plotting-in-matlab)  to come up with X-axis labels for my graph. However, I want Matlab to treat the labels as tex code. In other words, when I have K_1, I want Matlab to display it as K subscript 1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit ugly solution, but still...

You can remove the ticks and add `text` elements manually:

```
x = 1:5;
y = x.*x;
plot(x, y, 'b')
set(gca, 'XTick',[]);
text(1,-0.8,'A_1');
text(2,-0.8,'B_1');
text(3,-0.8,'C_1');
text(4,-0.8,'D_1');
text(5,-0.8,'E_1');
```

[image]

Comment: +1, this is actually the method [recommended by matlab support](http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-5HAF0I/) of doing that, so you can not figure out anything less ugly ;)

Comment: @angainor, good to know once again that beauty is in the eyes of the beholder :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to @Andrey. You could use `arrayfun` to make it easier to enter the labels:

```
x = 1:5;
y = x.*x;
plot(x, y);
set(gca, 'XTick',[]);
labels = {'K_1', 'K_2', 'K_3', 'K_4', 'K_5'};
arrayfun(@text, x, -1*ones(size(x)), labels);
```

You could even generate an arbitrary number of labels using:

```
labels = strcat({'K_'},int2str((1:5)'))';
```