# Show time in Matlab from csv file

Tags: matlab, date, time, graph

How do I show **10/9/2013 17:00** timestamps extracted from csv file to display in matlab graph x-axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672637/how-to-use-string-as-data-for-plotting-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

Let's write some time-stamped data into a file

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv', 'w');               // open file for writing
for t = 1:10
  fprintf(fid, '%s,%f\n', datestr(now()), t); // write a line
  pause(rand);                                // pause for a bit
end
fclose(fid);                                  // always close your files!
```

The contents of the file is now

```
11-Oct-2013 09:03:55,1.00000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:56,2.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:56,3.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:57,4.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:57,5.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:58,6.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:59,7.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:03:59,8.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:04:00,9.000000
11-Oct-2013 09:04:00,10.000000
```

To read it out with timestamps, you can do

```
fid = fopen('myfile.csv');                       // open for reading
cts = textscan(fid, '%s %f', 'Delimiter', ',');  // read comma delimited file
d = datenum(cts{1});                             // convert first col to datenum
v = cts{2};                                      
fclose(fid);                                     // always close your files!
```

And plot it with timestamp labels like this

```
plot(d, v), datetick('x')
```